# Waiting for nested BackgroundWorkers to complete

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a UI button that spawns a BackgroundWorker. This BackgroundWorker spawns several BackgroundWorkers that perform some operations. Is there a way to wait for all the inner BackgroundWorkers to complete in the main BackgroundWorker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main worker code, you can check the [IsBusy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.isbusy.aspx) of the other workers

*"Gets a value indicating whether the BackgroundWorker is running an asynchronous operation."*

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorkerMaster_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorkerMaster.DoWork
    Do While bgwChild1.IsBusy AndAlso bgwChild2.IsBusy
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) 'wait for a small amount of time
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is actually not very good solution because it will burn CPU without doing anything useful. If you add `Thread.Sleep` to the cycle body it will help a little, but still it will not exit immediately when workers finish.

Comment: @Andrey - Agree with the Thread.Sleep - I will add this, but I imagine real world impact on the CPU will be negligible.

Comment: this solution will work but in cases when immediate notification of end of async operations is necessary it will not work very well.

Comment: no, if you do it without Thread.Sleep impact will be huge, you can try.

Answer (score 5):

You can create [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx), pass it to spawned background workers, then in the end of background worker code call [Release](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6caa9s64.aspx) method. In the main worker call [WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) exact amount of times equal to number of spawned workers. Make sure to wrap everything in `try ... finally` so that your application doesn't hang if something goes wrong.

If you are using .net 4 consider using [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx), it is lightweight version with same functionality.

Comment: I would not Release at the end of the background worker code (in DoWork) because the code inside may crash and never reach the end of DoWork. I'd put it in RunWorkerCompleted so that it's always called.

Comment: @svenv that's why I mentioned wrapping it into try finally block.